# DC motor as a generator as well as a motor in a car

Tags: dc, dc-motor, generator

Not sure if this was asked before, but can I use a DC motor to power the front axle, but then use the same DC motor as a generator when the vehicle is braking. Can I have a link which helps choosing which DC motors is best as a generator

Comment: Yes you can. And Stack Exchange does not deal in links. Maybe you should ask how to choose a suitable motor.

Comment: Typically the regeneration braking is a side effect, you would pick your electric motor based on the motoring requirements, and then utilize whatever generation properties it has. Is the primary function of your motor in regeneration, or motoring?

Comment: This can be, and occasionally *is* done, but it's not trivial.  Braking a vehicle needs to be done with care to keep the amount of braking appropriate, and putting energy back into a battery pack has to be done with awareness of permissible charge rate and state.  This is *not* a simple design problem, which makes doing it on any practical level well beyond the scope of a question here.  Realistically you'd be buying a motor-controller-battery system with regenerative braking as an advertised feature.

Comment: "For my case, I am only planning on using the electric motor to drive the front axle until it reaches 10kph. Thereafter the IC engine powers the rear axle. Then, when braking from 50kph, the motor should capture the energy from the front axle. I am not considering the case of the vehicle in reverse" Bon Beyer, this is how I plan to use the motor.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're asking for is *4 quadrant control*.

What that means is, the motor and controller can implement 4 different modes:

- 1. Motor going clockwise, controller applying clockwise drive (forward)
- 2. Motor going anti-clockwise, controller applying anti-clockwise (reverse)
- 3. Motor going clockwise, controller applying anti-clockwise drive (braking forward)
- 4. Motor going anti-clockwise, controller applying clockwise (braking reverse)

In addition to that, when doing braking, an appropriately-designed motor + controller combo can implement *regeneration* (transferring energy to the battery) instead of just shedding kinetic energy as heat.

More here: https://www.pmdcorp.com/resources/type/articles/get/regenerative-braking-part-i-steady-state-analysis-article

That all said, you really need to buy the motor and controller as a system, because different traction motor types (BLDC, induction, brushed, etc.) have different driver needs for drive and regen capability.

BONUS: Different traction motor types used in cars.
https://circuitdigest.com/article/different-types-of-motors-used-in-electric-vehicles-ev

Comment: For my case, I am only planning on using the electric motor to drive the front axle until it reaches 10kph. Thereafter the IC engine powers the rear axle. Then, when braking from 50kph, the motor should capture the energy from the front axle. I am not considering the case of the vehicle in reverse

Comment: I think that it’s not unreasonable to ask that the motor also work in reverse, for parking and other low-speed maneuvers. It would be kind of annoying to require the engine to back out of a parking stall, then have it shut off for forward motion. No hybrid car that I know of works that way. You should price it out both ways. My guess is if your controller already supports regen in 2Q mode, 4Q will come practically ‘for free’ as the bridge drivers will already be there.